# NET Core 3 service - Service Manager won't wait for service startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, service, wait, .net-core-3.1

I have application running as service. The application is starting up several seconds, because of connection to database etc. I have another service application depending on the first one.

Therefore I need to distinguish 'starting phase' from the 'running phase', so I know when to start another service.

To simplify problem, I have service declared like following example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
       {
           services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
       })
       .UseWindowsService();
}

public class Worker : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // simulate loading... non of this cause wait
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

I'm reproducing this issue by starting up the program with Windows Service Manager and it's started within a second, definitely not 10 seconds (in this case).

Note #1: I have played with inhering from BackgroundService class, but result was pretty much same.

Note #2: The behavior is same on linux with systemd, when using extension method `.UseSystemd()`.

Is there any way how can I split the starting of service from its execution?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: The Windows service that hosts your app obviously needs to be started before it can run your hosted service...

Answer (score 4):

First, I recommend that you [raise an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues) with MS requesting this behavior. There's a [number of unexpected behaviors with .NET Core Win32 Services](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html).

`UseWindowsService` installs a `WindowsServiceLifetime`, which handles the interaction between the .NET Core host and the Win32 SCM. The source code for that type is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/4becf241089932aa1f1e7f3ab4155a437fd3dba1/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetime.cs).

Particularly, the `OnStart` implementation looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  _delayStart.TrySetResult(null);
  base.OnStart(args);
}
```

So, when the SCM sends a Start request, it will allow the .NET host startup to continue (`_delayStart.TrySetResult`), but then it will not wait for the startup to complete before returning from `OnStart` (which signals to the SCM that the service is started).

You'll need to block `OnStart` until the startup has completed. Interestingly, `WindowsServiceLifetime` itself has a pattern that you can use for this; when the SCM sends a Stop request, `WindowsServiceLifetime` starts the .NET host shutdown process *and then waits for it to complete* before returning from `OnStop`:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
  ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
  // Wait for the host to shutdown before marking service as stopped.
  _delayStop.Wait(_hostOptions.ShutdownTimeout);
  base.OnStop();
}
```

`_delayStop` is hooked up during the `WaitForStartAsync` method, which [acts as two things](https://andrewlock.net/introducing-ihostlifetime-and-untangling-the-generic-host-startup-interactions/): it provides a way for an `IHostLifetime` to pause the Host startup (in this case, until `OnStart` is called), and it provides initialization-level hooks for the `IHostLifetime` to hook into Host events.

The relevant parts of this method are:

```
public Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  ...
  ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
  {
    _delayStop.Set();
  });
  ...
  return _delayStart.Task;
}
```

In other words, "notify me via `_delayStop` when the host is done shutting down, and delay the host startup until I set `_delayStart`".

What you need to do is use the same pattern to delay the `OnStart` method. So you'll need a `CustomWindowsServiceLifetime` with a signal for `_applicationStarted`, set that signal when the application has completed starting, and block on that signal in the overridden `OnStart`. However, since we need to override `OnStart`, we also need to provide our own `_delayStart`:

```
public sealed class CustomWindowsServiceLifetime : WindowsServiceLifetime, IHostLifetime
{
  private ManualResetEventSlim _applicationStarted = new ManualResetEventSlim();
  private TaskCompletionSource<object> _delayStart = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

  public CustomWindowsServiceLifetime(IHostEnvironment environment, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<HostOptions> optionsAccessor)
    : base(environment, applicationLifetime, loggerFactory, optionsAccessor)
  {
    ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
    _applicationStarted = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  }

  private IHostApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

  public new Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
    {
      _applicationStarted.Set();
    });

    return Either(base.WaitForStartAsync(cancellationToken), _delayStart.Task);

    async Task Either(Task a, Task b) => await await Task.WhenAny(a, b);
  }

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
    // Allow host startup to continue.
    _delayStart.TrySetResult(null);

    // Wait for host startup to complete before returning to SCM.
    _applicationStarted.Wait();
    base.OnStart(args);
  }
}
```

This is completely untested (not even compiled), but it may work.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to complete the excellent answer from [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) - thank you so much!! - with minor details.

Code that compiles on .NET Core 3.1 is provided below (99% identical to the example provided).

```
public sealed class CustomWindowsServiceLifetime : WindowsServiceLifetime, IHostLifetime
{
    private ManualResetEventSlim _applicationStarted;
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _delayStart = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    private IHostApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

    public CustomWindowsServiceLifetime(
        IHostEnvironment environment, 
        IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
        IOptions<HostOptions> optionsAccessor
        ) : base(environment, applicationLifetime, loggerFactory, optionsAccessor)
    {
        ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
        _applicationStarted = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    }


    public new Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            _applicationStarted.Set();
        });

        // Must wait 
        return Either(base.WaitForStartAsync(cancellationToken), _delayStart.Task);

        async Task Either(Task a, Task b) => await await Task.WhenAny(a, b);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Allow host startup to _proceed_
        _delayStart.TrySetResult(null);

        // Wait for host startup to _complete_ before returning to SCM.
        // -> only then will base.OnStart complete _delayStart.Task
        _applicationStarted.Wait();
        base.OnStart(args);
    }
}
```

Configure this lifetime by adding the following to your Host creation:

```
hostBuilder.UseWindowsService();
hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, CustomWindowsServiceLifetime>());
```

If you got here because (like me) you were struggling with Windows Services and .NET Core, may I also take the opportunity to recommend the following resources:

https://andrewlock.net/introducing-ihostlifetime-and-untangling-the-generic-host-startup-interactions/

https://cdmana.com/2021/06/20210625104851403p.html

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/servicebase-gotcha-recovery-actions.html

Comment: Ran into this issue myself. Very frustrating. Thank you both for the very useful fix. One thing I may add: I would put a `if (WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService())` prior to adding the singleton - otherwise when running the app in console it will crash.